# Scikit-learn: find records with maximum residuals

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am modelling a linear equation with `scikit-learn`,

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
regressor = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)  
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', round(metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred),2))
print('Max Absolute Error:', round(metrics.max_error(y_test, y_pred),2))
print('R2 score:', round(metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred),2))
```

Train set size is 35k records, test set size is 9k records

I get coefficients which are very much inline with what I am expecting: `R2` is higher than 0.98, MAE is low (around 13-14, for predicted values of 5000-10000; this was expected, due to measuring tool precision).

However, I took a look at `max_error` and it is huge: over 1500; and this I cannot explain right away.

Is there a way to find the records which have the residual equal to `max_error`, or greater than a certain value ? Probably I did not do a proper data cleaning before running the model, but I'd like to take a look at those records, to see if data cleaning is the problem, or if it's something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for residuals that are above a certain threshold, not a max error. Max error is simply the maximum out of all residuals.

You can do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

y_true = np.array([100, 200, 300, 400, 500])
y_pred = np.array([200, 100, 100, 100, 100])

# compute residuals in their absolute values
residuals = map(abs, y_true - y_pred)

TOLERATION = 300
violation_idxs = []

for i, resid in enumerate(residuals):
    if resid >= TOLERATION:
        violation_idxs.append(i)

# this will give you indexes of all the entries that are
# violating your threshold
print(violation_idxs) # [3, 4] in this case

# and to see the entries that are violating the threshold
print(y_true[violation_idxs])
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.  I also edited slightly my post to clarify the residual vs. max_error topic, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract `y_pred` from `y_test`, and take the absolute value. This will give you the absolute difference for each datapoint.

You can then use `np.argmax` to get the index with the highest error, or `np.argsort` to get an array of indices, sorted from *low* to *high*, i.e., the last index of the array returned by `np.argsort` is the same index as `np.argmax`.

A code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

error = abs(y_pred - y_test)
max_error = np.argmax(difference)
max_errors = np.argsort(difference)[-10:]

X_test[max_error]
X_test[max_errors]
```

You can also sanity check whether this is correct by checking whether `max(error)` is the same value as returned by `metrics.max_error`.